# Talend: Task Execution Fails when re-built sub-job is deployed

Tags: talend

We have a perfectly working Talend Workflow which has 4 sub-jobs. One of the jobs needed a change, so we modified it and re-built the job within Talend Open Studio. Copied the jar to our production machine. However, when the Task executed, it failed with a "No Class Def Found" error message.

So, is this not how its supposed to be done? Do we have to re-build and re-deploy the main task and all the sub-jobs even for a minor change in a sub-job? Any ideas?

TIA,
Bee

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild and deploy the main job.
I don't know why, mays be have you increased the version of your subjob ?